# Проблема с текстурами в Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin, текстура

Как добавить свои текстуры в xamarin? Куда их надо закидывать и где прописывать? Пытался просто закидывать по пути **C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App\App\obj\Debug\res\drawable** но отдуда они удаляются при отладке.

Answer (score 1):

Добавить медиа файлы можно в папку Resources/drawable андроид проекта, поставить BuildAction:AndroidResource, затем получить к ним доступ следующим образом:

```
public static class ResourceLoader
{
    public static Stream StreamResource(string baseName)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(ResourceLoader).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(baseName);
        return stream;
    }
}

ResourceLoader.StreamResource("AssemblyName.Folder1.Folder2.file.png"));
```

еще вариант:
имея в папке "drawable" файл с именем "background.png" (Android resource)

```
public static void LoadBitmapDataFromResource(int resourceId)
{
    Bitmap b = 
       BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(
          Forms.Context.Resources, resourceId);

    LoadBitmapDataToTexture(b);
    b.Recycle();
}

public static int DrawableResourceIdFromName(string name)
{
    return ResourceIdFromNameAndResourceType(name, "drawable");
}

public static int ResourceIdFromNameAndResourceType(string name, string resourceType)
{
    var context = Forms.Context;
    return context.Resources.GetIdentifier(name, resourceType, context.PackageName);
}

LoadBitmapDataFromResource(DrawableResourceIdFromName("background1"));
```